# New line or Carraige Return syntax problems

Tags: visual-studio-2010, c++-cli, multiline

Im pretty new to coding, heres my problem.

```
Results->Text = "G55 > Y" + System::Convert::ToString(destY);
```

"Results" is a System.Windows.Forms.Textbox "multiline btw", or so says VS.

That line works fine, but i need a "new line or CR" at the end, so that i can repeat that line with different Literals and a different var in ToString.

For days now ive tried different syntax's ive read about, and i cant get it to take any of them.

Or even a complete different way to input text into Results->Text that would allow for tidy multiline use.

Sidenote: since im using ->Text and System::Convert::ToString in VC, would this code be considered just c++ or .net or CLI? to tighten my searches.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have you tried `System::Environment::NewLine`? This will give you CrLf on Windows and whatever is correct for Linux/OS X on those platforms.

Comment: yes thank you!

->Text = ->Text + System::Environment::NewLine + " new stuff"


did the trick!

Answer (score 0):

Being completely unfamiliar with .NET, I could be completely wrong, but surely adding a `+ "\n"` to the end of your line would do the job? Or failing that, a `+ "\r\n"`?

Comment: I couldnt get it working, and yes i tried like that i think.
->Text doesnt allow it i think.

Comment: If I recall correctly, having just \n is what confuses the textbox. "\r\n" should work the same as my answer.